# MONGODB - find on "_id" with JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb, find, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am trying to do this query :

```
db.indexInverse.find({_id:ObjectId("5a153409b9c52933c8aab068")}).pretty()
```

with Java ...

actually i try many things ... but that don't find my document ...

```
Document vraiDoc = collectionIndexInverse.find(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("\"" + idDoc + "\""))).first();
```

OR

```
Bson query = (Bson) new BsonString("{ _id:ObjectId(\"" + idDoc + "\")}");
Document vraiDoc = collectionIndexInverse.find(query).first();
```

OR

```
Bson query = (Bson) new BsonString("{ _id:ObjectId(idDoc)}");
Document vraiDoc = collectionIndexInverse.find(query).first();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first attempt to are double quoting the `ObjectId` value.

This will work:

```
Document vraiDoc = collectionIndexInverse.find(
    Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("5a153409b9c52933c8aab068"))
).first();
```

More generally, given these documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b86ff639f9ba0f9c0dccf6"),
    ...
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c0e662ac11a822d4e5da27"),
    ...
}
```

The following command will return the first document ...

```
find(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("59b86ff639f9ba0f9c0dccf6"))).first();
```

... and the following command will return the second document:

```
find(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("59c0e662ac11a822d4e5da27"))).first();
```

Comment: I'm guessing that when you wrote "it return already "null"" you mean that this returns null: `collectionIndexInverse.find(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("5a153409b9c52933c8aab068")))`? If so, then the `collectionIndexInverse` does **not** contain a document with `_id: ObjectId("5a153409b9c52933c8aab068")`. Perhaps it would help if you update your question to include a document taken from `collectionIndexInverse`.

Comment: Excellent. Worked with MongoDB 3.12.8. Most of the examples I found wouldn't work. TIA.